# Using Caffe in C++; Unable to pass caffe::SolverParameter to function without error

Tags: c++, ubuntu, caffe

I am attempting to compile the "Hello World XOR" C++ example given by:

https://medium.com/@shiyan/caffe-c-helloworld-example-with-memorydata-input-20c692a82a22

Hardware:
EX50-UD3R Motherboard
GT-640 NVidia cards (2 Cards)
Intel 980 (6 core)
16Gig (4x4) DDR3 RAM

Environment:
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS   Kernel: 4.4.0-78-generic
Eclipse Neon3 R4.6.3
CUDA 8.0
Caffe:  whatever ver I downloaded from Berkley on 06/04/2017

I followed the installation instructions for installing Caffe in Ubuntu 16.04:  https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide

and all the make commands succeeded.

However when I try to use the libraries in a simple cpp program:

```
#include <memory>

#include <cstdlib>    // Provides NULL, rand, size_t;
#include <stdio.h>  // For printf
#include <cstring>  // For string
#include "/home/caffe-master/include/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.hpp"
#include "/home/caffe-master-path>/include/caffe/caffe.hpp"

void blah( caffe::SolverParameter *sp);

int main()
{
... standard c++ code to generate random data deleted for brevity...
    caffe::SolverParameter solver_param;  // No errors given here for this declaration

    blah( solver_param);   // Simple function created to test error, same error appears here

    caffe::ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie( path, &solver_param);  // Actual function from XOR example, same error

    caffe::ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie("./solver.prototxt", &solver_param);  // This also gives same error

    boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Solver<float> > solver(caffe::SolverRegistry<float>::CreateSolver(solver_param)); // Same error here

... code that would of passed random data to caffe deleted ...
    return 0;
}


void blah( caffe::SolverParameter *sp)
{
    std::cout << "BLAH: " << sp->rms_decay_;
    return;
}
```

In Eclipse Neon I get the following error for any line that includes the variable solver_param including the lines that where I created the simple function blah which takes one argument of type caffe::SolverParameter *

Invalid arguments 'Candidates are:
void ReadSolverParamsFromTextFileOrDie(const std::__cxx11::basic_string,std::allocator> &, ? *)'  caffe_hellow.cpp    /caffe  line 47 Semantic Error

I tried setting the full paths in the include path and that got rid of some errors, I added the libpath in eclipse to include caffe and boost and that got rid of more errors leaving only this one for now. I've been searching for a solution, looking at the .hpp caffe files to try to understand them and trying different settings in eclipse to get rid of this error but nothing works.  Casting did not work either.

For some reason it does not recognize any variable declared as type SolverParameter as a compatible argument to a function that requires it.  The error message gives "? *" as the argument type.  What does that mean?  Can you help?  Thank you.

Comment: have you built caffe? and caffe.proto?

Comment: I created the library using the protoc command
and included the file caffe.pb.h, 
however it still gives same error unfortunately.

Comment: it seems like you are using c++11 compiler. Are you sure caffe support it? Is it possible some compilation flags should be added?

Comment: Hi, I had the Tool Chain Editor set to Cross GCC and I changed it to Linux GCC but still same error.  /usr/bin/g++ links to /usr/bin/g++-5.   I don't know if version is too new or old in this case.   g++  flags -I<stuff> and -O0 -g3 Wall -c -fmessage-length=0.  For linker just -L to give paths for lib files.   I don't know much about IDE settings just started using IDE to compiler "more than one file" projects so it is new to me.  Any idea what flag I could add or change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include

```
#include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"
```

For all caffe.proto related declarations

Comment: Unfortunately I generated the file and included it caffe.pb.h  .  Still complains with same error.

Comment: I am able to compile now.  It is a consequence of being a noob at using IDE.  I had to add the libraries in Project->Properties->GCC C++ Linker-> Libraries (-l):  caffe    boost_system    glog ... and this may not be needed ... cuda.   I also needed to add -L paths.
I also needed to update either /etc/environment or .bashrc to include the paths for caffe and cuda in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable.    Though again cuda may not be needed but I plan to use Cuda-C to access the GPU processors.

Comment: @OscarGarcia I am not an expert on Linux IDEs, but IMHO it is best compiling using make outside the IDE...

Comment: Thank you Shai, I would have tried console command make to see exact errors next but I know so very little about make.  My c++ experience prior to this has been confined to compiling single giant one file .c and .cpp programs.  The answer is Eclipse Neon is a blank slate for libraries and I have to add them to the search path.  Something obvious to experienced users but a noob like me needed to learn that concept first.   Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to compile now. It is a consequence of being a noob at using IDE.
I had to add the libraries in Project->Properties->GCC C++ Linker-> Libraries (-l):
caffe
boost_system
glog
... and this may not be needed ... cuda

I also needed to add -L paths for the above. Then I needed to update either /etc/environment or .bashrc to include the paths for caffe and cuda in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable otherwise I would get an unable t link binary error. Again cuda may not be needed to solve this error the other three sure are.  I plan to use Cuda-C to access the GPU processors.   Thank you Shai for your response on the protoc item it lead me to the other comments on including libraries.